# How can we set http_proxy permanantly RHEL

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have tried setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` using below command; but the value did not retain in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4. How can we set this value permanently and applicable for all users ?

```
export http_proxy=http://my-proxy-address:8081/
export https_proxy=http://my-proxy-address:8081/
```

Current proxy was check by using commands:

```
echo "$http_proxy"
echo "$http_proxy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the exports to a script that you put in `/etc/profile.d`. Is will be sourced by the user profiles.